# Connecting to an Android Hotspot from Ubuntu

Tags: network-manager, rfkill, lspci

I'm unable to connect to my Android hotspot with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my Dell XPS 13.

With WPA-PSK:

```
Mar 18 08:45:13 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552898713.4625] device (wlp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'androidhotspot' (db96cfa5-d6c6-448d-b1b0-63d05fb1ca08)
Mar 18 08:45:13 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552898713.4627] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="db96cfa5-d6c6-448d-b1b0-63d05fb1ca08" name="androidhotspot" pid=3615 uid=1000 result="success"
Mar 18 08:45:13 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552898713.4628] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Mar 18 08:45:13 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552898713.4631] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Mar 18 08:45:13 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552898713.4639] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Mar 18 08:45:13 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552898713.4642] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'androidhotspot' has security, but secrets are required.
Mar 18 08:45:13 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552898713.4642] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Mar 18 08:45:13 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552898713.4690] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Mar 18 08:45:13 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552898713.4694] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Mar 18 08:45:13 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552898713.4696] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'androidhotspot' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Mar 18 08:45:13 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552898713.4699] Config: added 'ssid' value 'androidhotspot'
Mar 18 08:45:13 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552898713.4702] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Mar 18 08:45:13 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552898713.4702] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Mar 18 08:45:13 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552898713.4702] Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
Mar 18 08:45:13 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552898713.4724] sup-iface[0x26caac0,wlp2s0]: config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Mar 18 08:45:13 ubuntu-laptop wpa_supplicant[1808]: wlp2s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with d8:c7:71:df:b3:78 (SSID='androidhotspot' freq=2412 MHz)
Mar 18 08:45:13 ubuntu-laptop kernel: [97878.656775] wlp2s0: authenticate with d8:c7:71:df:b3:78
Mar 18 08:45:13 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552898713.4899] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> authenticating
Mar 18 08:45:13 ubuntu-laptop kernel: [97878.664262] wlp2s0: send auth to d8:c7:71:df:b3:78 (try 1/3)
Mar 18 08:45:13 ubuntu-laptop kernel: [97878.766637] wlp2s0: send auth to d8:c7:71:df:b3:78 (try 2/3)
Mar 18 08:45:13 ubuntu-laptop kernel: [97878.872696] wlp2s0: send auth to d8:c7:71:df:b3:78 (try 3/3)
Mar 18 08:45:13 ubuntu-laptop kernel: [97878.982584] wlp2s0: authentication with d8:c7:71:df:b3:78 timed out
Mar 18 08:45:13 ubuntu-laptop wpa_supplicant[1808]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="androidhotspot" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
Mar 18 08:45:13 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552898713.8550] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Mar 18 08:45:23 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552898723.8600] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar 18 08:45:25 ubuntu-laptop wpa_supplicant[1808]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="androidhotspot"
Mar 18 08:45:25 ubuntu-laptop wpa_supplicant[1808]: wlp2s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with d8:c7:71:df:b3:78 (SSID='androidhotspot' freq=2412 MHz)
Mar 18 08:45:25 ubuntu-laptop kernel: [97890.983648] wlp2s0: authenticate with d8:c7:71:df:b3:78
Mar 18 08:45:25 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552898725.8168] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Mar 18 08:45:25 ubuntu-laptop kernel: [97890.990920] wlp2s0: send auth to d8:c7:71:df:b3:78 (try 1/3)
Mar 18 08:45:25 ubuntu-laptop kernel: [97891.094745] wlp2s0: send auth to d8:c7:71:df:b3:78 (try 2/3)
Mar 18 08:45:26 ubuntu-laptop kernel: [97891.200708] wlp2s0: send auth to d8:c7:71:df:b3:78 (try 3/3)
Mar 18 08:45:26 ubuntu-laptop kernel: [97891.302766] wlp2s0: authentication with d8:c7:71:df:b3:78 timed out
Mar 18 08:45:26 ubuntu-laptop wpa_supplicant[1808]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="androidhotspot" auth_failures=2 duration=20 reason=CONN_FAILED
Mar 18 08:45:26 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552898726.1629] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Mar 18 08:45:36 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552898736.1721] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar 18 08:45:39 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <warn>  [1552898739.1332] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Mar 18 08:45:39 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552898739.1333] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found') [50 120 53]
Mar 18 08:45:39 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552898739.1338] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Mar 18 08:45:39 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <warn>  [1552898739.1358] device (wlp2s0): Activation: failed for connection 'androidhotspot'
Mar 18 08:45:39 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552898739.1376] device (wlp2s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Mar 18 08:45:39 ubuntu-laptop kernel: [97904.313732] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
Mar 18 08:45:39 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552898739.1491] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> inactive
Mar 18 08:45:39 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <warn>  [1552898739.1493] device (wlp2s0): add_pending_action (1): 'scan' already pending
Mar 18 08:45:39 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: file devices/nm-device.c: line 10056 (nm_device_add_pending_action): should not be reached
Mar 18 08:45:39 ubuntu-laptop wpa_supplicant[1808]: wlp2s0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Mar 18 08:45:39 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552898739.9183] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
```

Without Auth:

```
Mar 18 08:52:45 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552899165.6882] device (wlp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'androidhotspot' (db96cfa5-d6c6-448d-b1b0-63d05fb1ca08)
Mar 18 08:52:45 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552899165.6887] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="db96cfa5-d6c6-448d-b1b0-63d05fb1ca08" name="androidhotspot" pid=7226 uid=1000 result="success"
Mar 18 08:52:45 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552899165.6892] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Mar 18 08:52:45 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552899165.6895] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Mar 18 08:52:45 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552899165.6908] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Mar 18 08:52:45 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552899165.6917] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'androidhotspot' requires no security.  No secrets needed.
Mar 18 08:52:45 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552899165.6918] Config: added 'ssid' value 'androidhotspot'
Mar 18 08:52:45 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552899165.6919] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Mar 18 08:52:45 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552899165.6919] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'NONE'
Mar 18 08:52:45 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552899165.7142] sup-iface[0x2627950,wlp2s0]: config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Mar 18 08:52:45 ubuntu-laptop wpa_supplicant[1808]: wlp2s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with d8:c7:71:df:b3:78 (SSID='androidhotspot' freq=2437 MHz)
Mar 18 08:52:45 ubuntu-laptop kernel: [98330.908170] wlp2s0: authenticate with d8:c7:71:df:b3:78
Mar 18 08:52:45 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552899165.7386] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Mar 18 08:52:45 ubuntu-laptop kernel: [98330.915544] wlp2s0: send auth to d8:c7:71:df:b3:78 (try 1/3)
Mar 18 08:52:45 ubuntu-laptop kernel: [98331.018518] wlp2s0: send auth to d8:c7:71:df:b3:78 (try 2/3)
Mar 18 08:52:45 ubuntu-laptop kernel: [98331.128479] wlp2s0: send auth to d8:c7:71:df:b3:78 (try 3/3)
Mar 18 08:52:46 ubuntu-laptop kernel: [98331.230510] wlp2s0: authentication with d8:c7:71:df:b3:78 timed out
Mar 18 08:52:46 ubuntu-laptop wpa_supplicant[1808]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="androidhotspot" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
Mar 18 08:52:46 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552899166.1013] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Mar 18 08:52:56 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552899176.1028] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar 18 08:52:56 ubuntu-laptop wpa_supplicant[1808]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="androidhotspot"
Mar 18 08:52:56 ubuntu-laptop wpa_supplicant[1808]: wlp2s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with d8:c7:71:df:b3:78 (SSID='androidhotspot' freq=2437 MHz)
Mar 18 08:52:56 ubuntu-laptop kernel: [98342.051465] wlp2s0: authenticate with d8:c7:71:df:b3:78
Mar 18 08:52:56 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552899176.8810] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Mar 18 08:52:56 ubuntu-laptop kernel: [98342.058955] wlp2s0: send auth to d8:c7:71:df:b3:78 (try 1/3)
Mar 18 08:52:57 ubuntu-laptop kernel: [98342.178616] wlp2s0: send auth to d8:c7:71:df:b3:78 (try 2/3)
Mar 18 08:52:57 ubuntu-laptop kernel: [98342.284726] wlp2s0: send auth to d8:c7:71:df:b3:78 (try 3/3)
Mar 18 08:52:57 ubuntu-laptop kernel: [98342.386634] wlp2s0: authentication with d8:c7:71:df:b3:78 timed out
Mar 18 08:52:57 ubuntu-laptop wpa_supplicant[1808]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="androidhotspot" auth_failures=2 duration=20 reason=CONN_FAILED
Mar 18 08:52:57 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552899177.2514] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Mar 18 08:53:07 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552899187.2588] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar 18 08:53:11 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <warn>  [1552899191.1330] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Mar 18 08:53:11 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552899191.1331] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found') [50 120 53]
Mar 18 08:53:11 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552899191.1338] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Mar 18 08:53:11 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <warn>  [1552899191.1348] device (wlp2s0): Activation: failed for connection 'androidhotspot'
Mar 18 08:53:11 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552899191.1365] device (wlp2s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Mar 18 08:53:11 ubuntu-laptop kernel: [98356.317844] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
Mar 18 08:53:15 ubuntu-laptop NetworkManager[1466]: <info>  [1552899195.1419] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> inactive
```

Any suggestions?

==== UPDATE

```
root@s:~# lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:143a]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
03:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d3] (rev 02)
root@s:~# rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Can you connect to other AP?

Comment: I can connect to other Wifi networks. Haven't tried another Android AP but I can connect to that Android Hotspot using a Mac.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I didn't even realise `rfkill` existed!

Answer (score 0):

Under Android mobile hotspot configuration menu check if "Allowed devices" whitelist is enabled. It seems that your laptop's WiFi card MAC is blacklisted.